# How do you read this format of data?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vb.net-2010

I have the following set of data (much larger, I've cut it down)

```
[{
    "title": "Brave",
    "year": "2012",
    "imdbid": "tt1217209",
    "scid": "2"
}, {
    "title": "The Watch",
    "year": "2012",
    "imdbid": "tt1298649",
    "scid": "1"
}]
```

I would like to be able to get the "title", for example **Brave** by finding **scid : 2**.

This isn't similar to other Json format that I am familiar with, because the other son has a parent, and child node, but this doesn't.

What would I need to do to be able to get the data I need?
I just need to be able to read the value in vb.net

EDIT: I belive this is Javascript Json format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a pretty standard and simple json to me.
You can get your object with this straightforward code.

First you have a class like this

```
Class myObj

    Public Property Title As String
    Public Property year As Integer 
    Public Property imdbid As String
    Public Property scid As Integer

End Class
```

Then you get it with

```
Sub Main()

    Dim input = File.ReadAllText("d:\temp\test2.json")
    Dim list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of myObj))(input)
    Dim obj = list.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.scid = 2)
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Title)
End Sub
```

(Of course you need to have a json parse library referenced in your project like newtonsoft.json as explained in other answer)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a package called [Newtonsoft.json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm),  it can be installed from `package manager console` like this:

```
install-package Newtonsoft.json
```

And include it like this:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
```

Your code may look like this:

```
Dim json As String = line

    Dim ser As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)
    Dim data As List(Of JToken) = ser.Children().ToList

    For Each item As JProperty In data
        item.CreateReader()
        Select Case item.Name
            Case "metadata"
                'MsgBox(item.Name)
            Case "data"
                For Each msg As JObject In item.Values

                    Dim scid As String = msg("scid")
                    Dim title As String = msg("title")

                Next
        End Select


    Next
```

You may refer to [these](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Samples.htm) code samples for more examples, good luck.